# I cant type the letter "s" in terminal , when I type the terminal changes from colour black to white please help

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

[That's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGD1q.png) the default terminal colour.

When I type letter "s" the terminal looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoCop.png) now.

Comment: what changes did you make recently?

Comment: I just went to the keyboard shortcuts in settings and accidentaly gave the letter "s" to do another function but I have tried restoring the keyboard shortcuts to ther default but nothing is changing

Comment: how did you change the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Disable/revert any/all customizations that aren't provided as options on a clean installation and try again. This includes uninstalling any "tweaks" or other software that alters your UI and any changes to configuration files.  This problem cannot be reproduced on an unaltered system, so it likely has to do with something you changed on your system.